# can't connect by SSH to Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, server, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Hi im new to Google cloud and i have a few questions:

i created two instances, and i can connect fine to them using the SSH button (that opens a new browser window) but my username is different between this machines (same google account):

1) in instance 1 my name is jhorten but in the instance 2 my name is jhorten_company_name_de i have a user called jhorten too, looks like they are sharing home folder but i automatically connect as jhorten_company_name_de, why? can i delete one of this users?

2) in the instance 1 i can connect using the linux ssh  client (ssh -i keys user@ip) but in the instance 2 i can't , i dont have a authorized_keys file in my home, how i can fix this?

Thanks guys

Comment: For your concern 1: By default,  a username for SSH sessions is generated from the email address logged into the account. To change the Linux Username, you could use [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#login_username) help center article.

Comment: For the concern 2: You could use [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) help center article to control access to Linux instances by creating SSH keys and editing public SSH key metadata. I hope this help you